# How to find any text within a value of an attribute of a tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

hi is there any way i can find specific text within a value of an atrribute of an HTML tag, To be more specific, im trying to find out if the  tag has "selected" within its "src" attribute e.g  in this case i need to find out if selected exists, I can go in other routes to do this but i need this as a condition.

I am selecting the src of the img tag and adding this special text, but i dont want it to keep on adding e.g  in this case its defeating the purpose of what im trying to do. I need to know if Selected has been inserted then ignore the particular image.

```
 $(this).hover(function(){
var currentName = $(this).attr("src");
var theNumToSub = currentName.length - 4;
$(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src").substr(0,theNumToSub)+"selected.jpg");

});
```

here is my code above for adding "Selected" in the first instance.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to familiarise yourself with all of the [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Can you show how src looks like. The actual string in src?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$(this).filter('[src$="selected.jpg"]');
```

it returns the same element if `src` ends with `selected.jpg`.

You can also filter if anywhere in `src` is `selected` keyword with:

```
$(this).filter('[src*="selected"]');
```

Comment: ended up using this method

Comment: @Wandile If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it with the tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) :

```
$("img[src*='selected']");
```

Comment: this looks good but remember Florian im trying to run away from using the element with this text in it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf()`

```
if($(this).attr("src").indexOf('selected')>0){
  //selected is there in src
  //your stuff here
}
```